# ASPX Button - nothing happens

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, email, button

I have a button on an aspx page that is supposed to send an email... my code appears to be setup correctly but when the button is clicked, nothing happens. Here is the code. It is intended to display an alert then redirect to the success page but nothing happens...

There is no onclick, but according to this, there shouldn't be: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t367616-using-handles-vb-vs-c.html Also the guide I got this code from doesn't use onclick either, although it's outdated.

The markup is:

```
<%@ Page Title="Sign Up" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="signup.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Email Service
</h2>

Re-enter your email address to confirm signup for updates. 
<br />
<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td><b>Email:</b></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UsersEmail" Columns="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SendEmail" Text="Sign Up"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The code-behind is:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Handles SendEmail.Click
    {
        try
        {
            //!!! UPDATE THIS VALUE TO YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS
            string ToAddress = "info@removed.org";

            //(1) Create the MailMessage instance
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(UsersEmail.Text, ToAddress);

            //(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties

            mm.Subject = UsersEmail.Text + " would like to sign up for updates";
            mm.Body = "Hello, I would like to sign up for updates. My email is " + UsersEmail.Text + ". Thank you.";
            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

            //(3) Create the SmtpClient object
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("[removed]");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            //(4) Send the MailMessage (will use the Web.config settings)
            smtp.Send(mm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strError = "<Script language=javascript>alert('Error');</Script>";
            Response.Write(strError);
            Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");

        }

        string strMsg = "<Script language=javascript>alert('Emailsent');</Script>";
        Response.Write(strMsg);
        Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");

        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Hello this is an Alert"")</SCRIPT>");
    }

}
```

}

I really doubt onclick is the solution anyway, because that not process any code..

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: try using onclick <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SendEmail" OnClick="SendEmail_Click" Text="Sign Up"/>

Comment: what is the name of your aspx.cs file? Is it "signup.aspx.cs" or is it "_Default.aspx.cs"?

Comment: I am wondering where the impression that it is not necessary to wire up event handlers for custom input actions came from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the handler to the event

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SendEmail" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="SendEmail_Click"/>
```

Next:

If you do this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strError = "<Script language=javascript>alert('Error');</Script>";
            Response.Write(strError);
            Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");

        }
```

You won't know anything about the error, for the first reason because a Redirect is made so the javascript code won't get the chance to run and the next reason is that catching the exception like this, doing nothing with it, you'll loose the instructions how to fix it.

You don't need to set the handler in markup, if you think it bloats it. You can do it for sure in code

```
public class _Default : System.Web.Page

{
    public _Default()
    {
         this.Init += (_o, _e) =>
          {
              SendEmail.Click += SendEmail_Click;
          };
    }
}
```

Comment: @AdrianIftode You are right about AutoEventWireup, I don't know why I had that brain fart. I still stand by the fact that the OnClick in the markup is not needed.

Comment: This is the answer... although now I'm getting hostname not found... something for me to figure out

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the eventhandler on the button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SendEmail" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="SendEmail_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** If `AutoEventWireup` attribute of the `Page directive` is set to true (or if it is missing, since by default it is true), the page framework calls page events automatically, specifically the `Page_Init and Page_Load` methods. In that case, no explicit Handler is needed.

The following handler will not be executed in case of `AutoEventWireUp = false`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

But this will be executed when the value is changed to True.

---

You second issue is you want to execute the button click event without declaring it's handler. This is really not possible. If you do not want to register it in HTML, there is another way to to it in code behind like below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Button b = new Button();
      b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
}
```